Node at intersections not rendering in tikz-3dplot
I just started using tikz-3dplot. I'm having an issue that I created two arcs and I want to place a labeled node at their intersection. For some reason I keep getting an error that the name of the node is not found. Any idea why this could be? The line of code for the node is right at the end of the MWE.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\R}{8}
\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

%sphere
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (\R);
\end{scope}


%horizon
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{35}}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw [name path =HB,thick,dashed] (\R,0) arc (0:180:\R);
\draw [name path =HF,thick] (-\R,0) arc (0:180:-\R);
\end{scope}

%celestial equator
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{35}{0}}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw [name path=CB,red,thick,dashed] ({-\R*sin(70)},{-\R*cos(70)}) arc (20:-10:-\R);
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=2pt,label=-45:$\alpha_{10}$] (MC) at (-\R,0) {}; 
\draw [name path =CF,red,thick] ({-\R*sin(70)},{-\R*cos(70)}) arc (-160:20:\R);
\end{scope}

%meridian
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[name path=meridiansouth,green,thick,dashed] (\R,0) arc (0:60:\R);
\draw[name path = northmeridbelowhorizon, green] (-\R,0) arc (0:60:-\R);
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt, label=right:$N'$] (NHor) at (-\R,0) {};
\node[fill, circle, inner sep = 1pt,name path = N, label=-135:$N$] (N) at ({-\R*sin(35)},{\R*cos(35)} ,0 ) {};
\draw[name path = meridiannorth, green, thick] (NHor) arc (180:60:\R);
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=right:$S'$] (S) at (\R,0) {}; 
\end{scope}

%This node doesnt want to render. but why?!!!
\node[fill, circle, inner sep=1pt,name intersections={of=CF and HF, by=E}, label=right:$E_{(\alpha_0)}$] at (E) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


